# Geodatabse 'ghost' feature dataset and feature layer duplicates

Tags: arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase, feature-class, feature-dataset, duplicates

Long story short, I reprojected my data into WGS 84 without realizing they would be exported into the same master source gdb, deleted the duplicates, but now see ghost duplicates of feature datasets and feature classes of what I deleted when first opening ArcGIS Pro.

Refreshing the geodatabase removes said ghosts, however, I am afraid that this problem will carry over to my data backup dataset and online data were I to update them.

Since then I deleted the duplicate feature dataset for all duplicates; however I still see the 'ghost' of the feature datasets below the real one. This seems to be an intermittent issue and goes away when I refresh my geodatabase.

I want to update my online data and backup data with this layer as it is the main layer, yet I do not want to export this problem to all my data. I have no way of going backwards with my Master gdb which is experiencing these ghost feature data sets and layers.

I have exported the master gdb into a folder to see if the problem is duplicated, yet I did not see any issue. I deleted the original gdb and copied the test gdb to replace, but I am still getting this issue today.

Images from today 10:45 PT

Ghost feature dataset duplicates

[image: Image 1]

Ghost duplicate feature classes

[image: Image 2]

Post geodatabase refresh

[image: Image 3]

Comment: This seems more like a Tech Support request than a Question. Have you contacted your Tech Support provider (Esri or international business partner, or local support provider (e.g., university)? There's clearly extra metadata in the system, but it's not clear where it is, or how to get rid of it.

Comment: back in the arcmap toolbox there was https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/deleting-duplicate-features.htm Compare by feature class, subtype, and geometry highest or lowest. I don't see this available in ArcGIS Pro 3.2 (yet).

Comment: Thanks for the info, my next step was to call tech support. This currently isn't preventing any regular performance, but is a cosmetic one and shouldn't be there. Not sure if it could lead to other issues down the process line.

Comment: If your backup is on a Windows Server is the history/previous version enabled?

Comment: I don't have backup on a windows server, it was just in another storage folder. In actuality I thought I had fixed the issue and subsequently updated my backup layer.

Comment: @Vince Thanks for the info, my next step was to call tech support. This currently isn't preventing any regular performance, but is a cosmetic one and shouldn't be there. Not sure if it could lead to other issues down the process line.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question in the ESRI community and the answer was to go into the Users folder location to my username, then AppData and then Roaming.

There I was instructed to rename the ESRI folder to ESRI_OLD.

A new ESRI folder auto creates and I am no longer seeing the ghost duplicated feature class selections in my geodatabases.